# index "pg_authid_oid_index" contains unexpected zero page at block 1

Tags: postgresql

İndex "pg_authid_oid_index" contains unexpected zero page at block 1 this.

İ can't login because of this error.

Even though i trust the settings in pg_hba.conf, i still get the same error.

Has anyone ever encountered such an error before?

Can I take a backup while the db is in this state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have corruption.

Assuming that that is the only corrupted file, you need to start the database in a mode where it doesn't try to use the system indexes.  Something like `pg_ctl start -o -P` should do that.  Then once connected as a superuser, rebuild the index `reindex table pg_authid;`

If you have corruption through more places than just that file and you don't have a backup, then you are pretty much screwed.

Comment: Yes.  But I actually did test it with -o -s (after manually corrupting the index and verifying I could not log in with a normal start) , and it bizarrely worked.